# OpenCart not redirecting to login page

Tags: php, opencart2.3

If user is not logged in and he visits wishlist page.(http://website/index.php?route=account/wishlist) he should redirect to login page (http://website/index.php?route=account/login) but instead, he stays on same page and it shows blank

Here is controller code

```
class ControllerAccountWishList extends Controller {
public function index() {
    if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', true);

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', true));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for it

There is error coming of Headers already sent while redirecting to wishlist or account. That I have fixed by adding ob_start() & ob_flush() in index.php file in OpenCart root directory.